Reinstall Windows 10 and keep Ubuntu
I don't use Windows 10 very much, but sometimes. I have forgotten the password and I don't have any Microsoft account and my laptop has one disk (an SSD). As I understand it is hard or almost impossible to install Windows 10 when there is an Ubuntu installation on the same SSD? I wonder how I can keep Ubuntu and the install Windows 10 and then put on my Ubuntu installation with all installed applications, settings and other files and grub.
In short, I want to keep my Ubuntu installation and reinstall Windows 10 and I don't have any password for Windows 10, and maybe there is a better way?

Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive? Windows 8, 10 & 11 keep the Product Key in UEFI. So if you install Windows in UEFI mode, it will automatically find its product key. But if drive is not gpt, Windows will erase drive. Either way be sure to have good backups & shrink enogh space so unallocated is available. Windows in UEFI mode wants lots of partitions & will use same ESP - efi system partition.
